# typeof<'x'> Results in "Type inference caused the type variable x to escape its scope"

Tags: f#

What does the "Type inference caused the type variable x to escape its scope." error mean in this case? I *am* trying to make it 'escape' via an attribute. What should I change to successfully get a Type instance for the `'x` type variable? I tried both dotnet-sdk 2.2.400 and 3.1.100...

```ml
type Z<'x>() =
  [<System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter(typeof<'x>)>]
  member this.M (a: 'x) = a
```

error FS3187: Type inference caused the type variable x to escape its scope. Consider adding an explicit type parameter declaration or adjusting your code to be less generic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The corresponding C# code gives a slightly more descriptive error [CS0416](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0416): "an attribute argument cannot use type parameters".  I think this is a fundamental .NET limitation, not an F# limitation, so finding a workaround may be nontrivial.